# X11 application from 'administrator' account

Tags: macos, permission, x11

Call me paranoid but my everyday account has no privileges.

I have a 'administrator' account who is in wheel. When I want to perform administrative tasks, I open a terminal and do

```
su - administrator
sudo ...
```

This works fine in most situations, except with X11 applications.

```
sudo xeyes
```

fails with

> Can't open display:

What I've tried:

- start X11 with the everyday user
- do `xhost +localhost` with everyday user
- do `export DISPLAY=:0` with administrator

How can I run a X11 application with the administrator account when my desktop runs with the everyday user?

Comment: Does `xhost +` work? Or are you too paranoid to try even that?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `ssh -X` to localhost?